# login and logout toggle via session

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

hi guys i am doing a school project. i would like to toggle a class when a user is logged in. I have the session working and the javascript is detecting the session but the classes are not toggling. Here is my code

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
 var userid = "<?php echo $username; ?>";//username is the session variable
 if (userid==(""))//indicaates that no one is logged in
 $('#det_login').toggleClass('hide'); 
 else
 $('#det_logout').toggleClass('hide');
</script>


<li id="det_login"><a href="javascript:login('show');" class="nav2"> login</a><li>

<li id="det_logout" class="hide"  ><a href="javascript:login2('show');" class="nav2"><?= $username ?> logout</a><li>
```

Please guys I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Thank for your help guys this is what i did. It was not toggling apparent because i had the javascript above the display statement.

```
                                <li id="det_login" class="show"   ><a href="javascript:login('show');" class="nav2">
login</a><li>

                         <li id="det_logout" class="show"  ><a href="javascript:login2('show');" class="nav2"><?= $username ?>
 logout</a><li>

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
 var userid = "<?php echo $username; ?>";
 if (userid==(""))
 {
 $('#det_logout').addClass('hide'); 
  $('#myaccount').addClass('hide');
   $('.divider2').addClass('hide');
 }
 else
$('#det_login').addClass('hide');
</script>
```

Comment: Don't mix PHP and JavaScript to begin with. Anyway you got 'hide' in both cases for your toggleClass. Also login2 is never defined, at least not in the code that you're showing us, so I wouldn't be expecting anything to happen. Check the console in your developer tools and show us full code if anything is missing.

Comment: HI i have login2 and login defined in a separate javascript file would you like me to paste the entire php and javascript file?

Comment: @user3002303:never ever do that..to motivate people to answer your question you got to simplify your question ..

Comment: If you reference something (i.e. use a function of some sort or use a variable or a constant) then you should include it with a well indented and separated code. I'm still curious why you have if else but still hide in them both.

Comment: the first hide is for login and the second logout. i got it done btw but since i am new i cannot answer the solution until after 8 hours

Answer (score 1):

First of all,what you are doing is not the correct way of doing things.

I think what you are trying to do is if a user is logged in,you set a session variable.If this user is logged in you try to show/hide some thing and vice versa..

For Toggle,this part is enough.I recommend not to use toggle since it is deprecated.

```
var flag = false;

$(document).on('click', '.login', function(event) {
    if (flag) {
        // logged in code
    }else{ //in your case if (userid==(""))
        // logout code
    }
    flag = !flag;
});
```

Simpler approach:

```
<script>
    var is_logged_in = "<?php echo $_SESSION['log_status'] ?>"; //$_SESSION['log_status']=true..assume
    if (is_logged_in) {
        //your code..$(".class or #id").addClass("xyz");//show,hide or any appropriate action
    } else {
        //some other action
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am very new to this(only started this month) and i don't quite understand the code you posted. Can you paste my code in it so i can see the syntax?

Comment: grab a good book about programming javascript,jquery,pho..its a far better way to learn rather than googling everything...Besides the code is pretty simple ..which part you dont understand

Comment: i am looking at the second approach where you have my code. Would my html go there? <li id="det_login"><a href="javascript:login('show');" class="nav2"> login</a><li>

Comment: no no no...i hope you have created a function called login..I dont know why you need to pass show as a param...it is good that you are trying to learn something..but your html does not go any where..and i would recommend you to keep you html cleaner and assign event handler in your javascript rather..and as i said for a begineer always grab a book..